# browser javascript creating custom events

Tags: javascript, events, dom, browser, mozilla

I don't unterstand this:

I try to create a custom event which should be fired when a list is fully loaded in a table body. Like this (executes after list is loaded):

```
  var event = new Event('mklistloaded', {
        name: 'listname'
  });

  document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

And this is the "receiving" end:

```
document.addEventListener('mklistloaded', function(e) {

    console.log('mklistloaded event: ' + JSON.stringify(e));

});
```

But console log prints out:

```
mklistloaded event: {"isTrusted":false}
```

That's quite the same as described in the mozilla example:

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the section in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) *"Adding custom data – CustomEvent()"*

```js
document.addEventListener('mklistloaded', function(e) {
  console.log('mklistloaded detail: ', e.detail);
});
// use CustomEvent() instead of Event()
var event = new CustomEvent('mklistloaded', {
  'detail': 'listname'
});

document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Note that it seems to require using the property name `detail`